# Why has FileZilla started timing out on Directory Listing since last week?

Tags: windows-7, ftp

FileZilla version 3.10 had always been able to list the files and directories on my domain at GoDaddy until last Friday. Now it times out after the LIST command.

I checked with GoDaddy Support and they were able to FTP my domain with FileZilla with no problems.

I have tried re-installing FileZilla. I have checked the Windows Firewall to see that there is an exception for FileZilla and there are rules for Incoming and Outbound ports. I created a rule in my Xfinity Router for FTP Ports.

I installed FileZilla on another computer on my LAN and it has the same timeout. The Debug Log for a session is:

```
2015-07-05 14:23:44 59416 1 Status: Disconnected from server
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx:21...
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 220 Microsoft FTP Service
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::Handshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: TLS Handshake successful
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: Protocol: TLS1.0, Key exchange: RSA, Cipher: AES-128-CBC, MAC: SHA1
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: USER XxxXsssss
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 331 Password required for KenFowler.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: PASS *************
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 230-FTP-SSL (AUTH TLS, Explicit FTPS or FTPES) security is available
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 230 User logged in.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 200 PBSZ command successful.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: PROT P
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 200 PROT command successful.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Connected
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: Measured latency of 64 ms
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: PWD
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: TYPE I
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 200 Type set to I.
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: PASV
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (97,74,215,122,198,113).
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2015-07-05 14:23:48 59416 1 Command: LIST
2015-07-05 14:23:49 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
2015-07-05 14:23:49 59416 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
2015-07-05 14:23:49 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
2015-07-05 14:23:49 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
2015-07-05 14:23:49 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
2015-07-05 14:24:09 59416 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
2015-07-05 14:24:25 59416 1 Status: Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own post because I found a fix.

Since the symptoms were seen on two computers and two FTP programs connected to the local Router/Cablemodem, I zeroed in on the Router Firewall. I found that the Xfinity Router Firewall was set for Medium Security. Medium level is set up to block Peer-to-Peer access on a wide range of ports. I believe the FTP Server was choosing ports in those ranges for data transfer.

Since the conditions for Medium level cannot be edited, I chose to use the Custom level. I set that up to allow Peer-to-Peer access on all ports - the only choice available - and that cured my FTP client problems.

I am perplexed as to why FTP worked on the Medium Security level until last week. I think Comcast/Xfinity must have rolled out a change to the modem. I know that Xfinity rolled out a new certificate last week which temporarily blocked me from sending mail.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... I had experience like you. I donwload newest Filezilla version and cant connect to my server. You need to find settings to disable SSL option. Or I would recommend you to use previous Filezilla version. I use Filezilla 3.8 and it is working fine on my end.